# How to limit the results to 1 row in Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle

I've this query which runs successfuly

```
SELECT customerNumber
FROM ORDERS 
GROUP BY customerNumber 
ORDER BY count(orderNumber) DESC
```

But when I try to limit the number of rows returned to 1, I get the following error

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Here's what I've tried :

```
SELECT customerNumber
FROM ORDERS 
GROUP BY customerNumber 
ORDER BY count(orderNumber) DESC
fetch first 1 row only;
```

and

```
SELECT customerNumber
FROM ORDERS 
GROUP BY customerNumber 
ORDER BY count(orderNumber) DESC
WHERE ROWNUM=1;
```

Comment: `fetch first 1 row only;` needs Oracle 12 - which version are you using? Are you trying to find the customer with the most orders?

Comment: It's an online editor so I don't know the version, but I'm trying to find customer with most orders.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Oracle you need to do the ordering first and then select `rownum`. Thus, you need to nest the query which returns the sorted data and take the filtering `WHERE` clause outside.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
 SELECT customerNumber
 FROM ORDERS 
 GROUP BY customerNumber 
 ORDER BY count(orderNumber) DESC
) resultSet
WHERE ROWNUM=1;
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked without using the `resultSet` as well. Why is that required?

Comment: @Satwik Oh, it's something that in SQL Server is required. I added it by reflex, since I haven't worked with Oracle for some time now. For this query you can just take it out, if you're using Oracle. [More info on why I added the alias to the result set](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16516/subqueries-aliases-same-as-main-queries-aliases).

Answer (score 1):

You can combine grouping and window functions to accomplish this.

```
select customernumber, num_orders
from (
  SELECT customerNumber, 
         count(*) as num_orders,
         dense_rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as rnk
  from orders
  group by customerNumber
) t
where rnk = 1;
```

The difference to a simple "get me only one row" is that this will also return multiple customers that have the same number of orders. If you don't want that, replace `dense_rank()` with `row_number()`

Answer (score 0):

the where condition must be placed  before the order by  (but seem that you need  the first row after the sorted  is done )

so you should  use a select this wya

```
  select * from (
    SELECT customerNumber
    FROM ORDERS 
    GROUP BY customerNumber 
    ORDER BY count(orderNumber) DESC
  ) t 
  WHERE ROWNUM=1;
```